# How does SockJS create an iframe

Tags: javascript, sockjs

I am using SockJS on my website and I am using the endpoint /msg

When I go to mysitename.com/msg/iframe.html, it shows this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script>
    document.domain = document.domain;
    _sockjs_onload = function(){SockJS.bootstrap_iframe();};
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1.0.0/sockjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Don't panic!</h2>
  <p>This is a SockJS hidden iframe. It's used for cross domain magic.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How does SockJS do this?

Comment: Any update on this issue? This is a security attack and I want to prevent that happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's being sat within org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService from spring websocket at backend.

For example:

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

private static final String SOCKJS_VERSION = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.3.0/sockjs.min.js";

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/handler").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    registry
        .addEndpoint("/handler")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS()
        .setClientLibraryUrl(SOCKJS_VERSION);
}
```

}

If you follow setClientLibraryUrl, you'll se where it's being worked out.

Check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/sockjs/support/AbstractSockJsService.java

and search for 'IFRAME_CONTENT'